# Class Inheritance from Pre-Existing Class C++

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, codeblocks

I'm writing a program that need a class inherited from the another class. How would I go about doing this?

I'm compiling with Code::Blocks 12.11

Comment: Try your favourite search engine instead of wasting SO's time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class ChildClass : public ParentClass {
};
```

The `public` says to make all members of `ParentClass` public (if they were public in `ParentClass`). Alternatively you can use `protected` or `private` to hide `ParentClass`'s members in `ChildClass`.